# How do I upload audio file with user Metadata to S3 using AWSS3TransferUtility

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to allow users to upload songs and metadata to an S3 folder. I'm having trouble uploading the audio (.mp3, .wav, etc.).

The user info is stored in a DynamoDB table, but I'd like to have the actual song stored in an s3 folder, and have the two connect.

With the following code I can only seem to upload the name of the audio file S3 but no actual data... I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
import AWSMobileClient
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider
import AWSAppSync
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaAccessibility
import MediaToolbox



class mediaUploadVC: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate{

    fileprivate let BUCKETNAME = "newtbxbkt-newtbxeniv"


    var avMusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
    var mpMediapicker: MPMediaPickerController!

    var mediaItems = [MPMediaItem]()
```

MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer

```
    fileprivate let s3Service: S3Service = S3Service()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }



    @IBAction func pickSongBtn(_ sender: UIView) {

          mpMediapicker  = MPMediaPickerController.self(mediaTypes:MPMediaType.music)
          mpMediapicker .allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
          mpMediapicker .popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
          mpMediapicker .delegate = self

        self.present(mpMediapicker , animated: true, completion: nil)



    }

    func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {

        avMusicPlayer.setQueue(with: mediaItemCollection)
        mediaPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        avMusicPlayer.play()


    }


    @IBAction func uploadData(_ data: Any) {


        let data: Data = Data() // Data to be uploaded

        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
        expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                print("upload in progress")
                // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
            })
        }

        var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
        completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let _ = error {
                    print ("There was an error uploading files... \(error.debugDescription)")
                    print ("Let us check response \(String(describing: task.response?.allHeaderFields))")
                    print ("Let us check response \(String(describing: task.response?.debugDescription))")
                } else {
                    print("Completed uploading file...")
                }
            })
        }
        userAPI.getuserId { (userCognitoId) in
            let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

            transferUtility.uploadData(data,
                                       bucket: self.BUCKETNAME,
                                       key: "protected/\(userCognitoId)/song1.mp3",
                contentType: "audio/mp3",
                expression: expression,
                completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                    (task) -> AnyObject? in
                    if let error = task.error {
                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }

                    if let _ = task.result {
                        // Do something with uploadTask.
                    }
                    return nil;
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data: Data = Data()
```

This is the offending line.

At the moment, you are uploading an empty Data. You’ll need to convert the file contents you wish to upload into that Data and upload that.

*Edit in response to comments:*
To retrieve data from a file at a given URL on the system, you can call

```
let fileURL: URL = ... // get a reference to the URL 
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) {
    // now you have the data
}
```

There is another initializer for the `AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask` which takes the URL as an argument, which may be simpler in your case.

Getting the data of an `MPMediaItem` involves getting its `assetURL`, creating an `AVAsset` and using an `AVAssetExportSession` to write the data to a URL on the system (usually in the Temporary directory).

There are other posts here which go into more detail of how to export `MPMediaItem` asset data, which you should be able to easily search for.

iOS limits you to accessing only files contained in the directories of your application (or application group) sandbox, so don't expect you will be able to get just any data from the device.

Comment: How would I convert the file contents of an (mp3 or .wav) file?  I apologize for my ignorance , I’m still learning  much of this.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, it seems like you would be trying to get the data out of the `MPMediaItem`, is that right?

Comment: Yes and no.  I would like to allow the user to be able to grab the music from anywhere on their device. I'm just not sure how to allow them access to other folders.

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to your clarification. Hope this gives you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. So would I just replace "let data: Data = Data()". with the code you provided. "let fileURL: URL = ... // get a reference to the URL 
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL) {
    // now you have the data
}"

Comment: Where do I get and write the "reference to the URL"

Comment: I believe it goes here. I'm just not sure how to write it. "... // get a reference to the URL "

Comment: @IBAction func uploadData(_ data: Any) {
         
               let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
        if (try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL)) != nil {
            // now you have the data
        }
        let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
        expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                
                print("upload in progress")
                // Do something e.g. Update a progress bar.
            })
        }

Comment: when I select a song from the apple playlist it plays the music out loud. I guess that's ok, but when I hit save, I get this error:

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x22e43c828) to 'NSData' (0x22e40cda8).
2019-09-02 17:06:52.935642-0400 new_tbx[3033:702871] Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x22e43c828) to 'NSData' (0x22e40cda8).
Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.

Comment: @TBX_Dev to get a reference to media URLs from a media collection, check out Apple’s documentation for the AVAssetExportSession I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @TBX_Dev your uploadData action has an argument named “data” which is of type “Any”. In your case, this is a UIButton. Assign the data from a URL to a local variable and upload that (in my answer I unwrapped the result with “if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL)”. It is not enough to only check if it is nil. Hope this gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still having trouble. Here is what I have:  @IBAction func uploadData(_ data: UIButton) {
              let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
          if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL){
        }

Comment: Here is the error: Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x2188ec828) to 'NSData' (0x2188bcda8).

Comment: I'm getting this when I pick the song:  2019-09-11 09:51:19.146467-0400 new_tbx[2795:568768] [SDKPlayback] -[MPMusicPlayerController play] completed error: Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 0" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 0, NSUnderlyingError=0x281b20570 {Error Domain=MPCPlayerRequestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Failed to send command 0 (MRSendCommandError = 4)" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to send command 0 (MRSendCommandError = 4)}}}

Comment: Your URL is invalid. Your Data is invalid. Set some breakpoints in your code and step through it so you can see where you’re going wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, Like I said I'm new to this, and only know the basics. Is it possible to grab the .mp3 file from other folders on the users device? Could it be that the URL and data are invalid because I'm trying to grab audio from the apple music playlist? I can't seem to write the code to grab a valid URL.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: @TBX_Dev If you share a link to your repo, I can try to give you a more detailed explanation with some code than I can here in the comments

Comment: I just created an account on GitHub Here is the path to the code: https://github.com/TraxBox?tab=repositories

Comment: Are you able to assist?

Comment: I created a pull request yesterday

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's a "pull request"?

Comment: @TBX_Dev check your github :)

Comment: Thx... Is it possible to maybe upload an audio file (.mp3) from any folder on a users device instead of forcing them to get it from their Apple Music folder? If so, how would revise the code.

Comment: Unless your app owns the source folder, no. Good luck!

Comment: Darn I really need a way for app users to browse there device's iCloud folders or wherever they might be keeping songs (mp3) and allow them to upload to S3 . Oh well... thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: Hey @TBX_Dev, i have updated the PR on github and commented on it there. Cheers